# Issue : New instance of activity created on resuming the app from background

Tags: android, android-activity, background, duplicates, resume

Whenever I put my application in background, navigate through some other apps and resume my app, a new instance of the last opened activity is getting created.

The onCreate() method is invoked again and the state of the activity where I paused my app is lost. Also after logout/exit from the app the duplicate instance of the activity remains on top. I am not using any flags while starting the activity. The default launch mode is used.

I have tried using FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP while starting the activity, but didn't work.

Can someone please suggest a way out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. Check the link.If the user is running many background tasks at the same time, the system might begin destroying background activities in order to recover memory, causing the activity states to be lost

Comment: Can you post some relevant code, please? Your onStart and onPause methods would be helpful.

Comment: You need to better mangage the app lifecycle. The activity will get destroyed in background if left there. Also how do you know there is a "dupliate instance" i.e. two running at the same time?

Comment: @Rarw Once I logout from the app, the same activity which I resumed stays at the top which suggests that there is a new instance of the activity created.

Comment: @Rinoy How does that suggest a new instance? You're assuming that logging out of your app is destroying the activity that was already running. This may not be the case. For example, if your log out button is designed to log the user out from your server, and uses an intent to return to the log in screen, it will not necessarily kill the previous activity. You could be "logged out" and still have the previous activity running. Can you post the log out code?

Answer (score 0):

check that if you use some flags for intent to start activity and also

check that if you handle onPause()  because whenever you press home button or out of the activity pause is called